# How to resize multiple photos (batch) in Apple Photos app on macOS

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, photos.app, monterey

Having 1 TB of photos and videos in Photos.app, one might want to resize some old photos or even videos so that the changes are perfectly (keeping all metadata) updated in the Photos.app and the overall size of it decreases.

We know that touching the originals within the package contents of .photoslibrary might result in corrupted library. I have tried resizing original photos with `sips`, `convert` or other programs in bash, and the changes are visible on Photos app. However the metadata is not updated (original is 4000x2000, resized is 640x480 and photos app still shows 4000x2000 while the photo is 640x480).

There are a lot of apps that interact with Photos.app like Photo Sweeper, Power Photos, etc. However I couldn't find any that allows to batch resize by editing.

Couldn't find a way to do that with Automator or applescript although there are scripts interacting with the Photos app.

Seems a very common use case but I couldn't find any answer on the web.

Tried below suggestions:

- Shortcuts on MacOS: the shortcut doesn't show up. Anyways it would create another file instead of modifying the original.
- RAW Power. No ability to Resize without cropping. It does multiple enhancement, but no multi resize.
- GraphicConverter 11, is not integrated with Photos.app. No difference with what I could do with `sips` or `convert` in bash. But that would change the contents of Photos.app and it would not be reflected in the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. [RAW Power](https://www.gentlemencoders.com/raw-power-for-macos/) does this.

- Select the photos/images in Raw Power.
- Choose **Export**
- adjust format, customize size and wether metadata (and which) should be saved.
- select or create Album within Apple’s Photos to export to.

Comment: Thank you! Shortcuts is meant for iOS as it is stated on that website you link. I tried it on Mac OS X and although having the Shortcuts app, it doesn't appear in the share menu of Photos.app. The other one I'm gonna try.

Comment: Tried RAW Power app. Can't find an option to bulk resize. There's a way to edit an image and apply changes to multiple. However, there seem no way to resize without cropping.

Comment: The short cut referenced before will be accessible via the menubar or as Quick Action on a Mac. To make sure of that use the settings in Apple’s ShortCuts after downloading and opening it.

Comment: Graphicconverter is not able to open Photos.app library, it's not integrated solution. It sees it as a folder.
Shortcuts app is not appearing in the share sheet for photos.app even following https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/shortcuts-mac/apd163eb9f95/5.0/mac/12.0. Under System Preferences>Extensions>Share Menu, there's no shortcuts app. Please read my question again and notice I'm trying to modify Photos.app library so that the size of photos is decreased both in Photos.app and actual HDD.

Comment: I just checked RAW Power - and it batch **exports** JPEGs (as well as a variety of others formats) with customized size and an option to strip the meta data. You can select or create an album within Photos to which these are then saved. Select the photos->choose export->adjust format, size, metadata->select album

Comment: This might be a workaround but not the solution to what I'm looking for as described in above description. With RAW Power I'd be exporting which is creating copies... I'm looking for compressing originals in place. I'd be processing 1000s of items so this needs to be automated. Can't be manual solution. I guess there might be a way via applescript or bash... But thanks anyways!